# Cleaning strings in R: add punctuation w/o overwriting last character

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I'm new to R and unable to find other threads with a similar issue.

I'm cleaning data that requires punctuation at the end of each line. I am unable to add, say, a period without overwriting the final character of the line preceding the carriage return + line feed.

Sample code:

```
Data1 <- "%trn: dads sheep\r\n*MOT: hunn.\r\n%trn: yes.\r\n*MOT: ana mu\r\n%trn: where is it?"
Data2 <- gsub("[^[:punct:]]\r\n\\*", ".\r\n\\*", Data1)
```

The contents of Data2:

```
[1] "%trn: dads shee.\r\n*MOT: hunn.\r\n%trn: yes.\r\n*MOT: ana mu\r\n%trn: where is it?"
```

Notice the "p" of sheep was overwritten with the period. Any thoughts on how I could avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

### Capturing group:

Use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) around your character class and reference the group inside of your replacement.

```
gsub('([^[:punct:]])\\r\\n\\*', '\\1.\r\n*', Data1)
      ^            ^             ^^^
# [1] "%trn: dads sheep.\r\n*MOT: hunn.\r\n%trn: yes.\r\n*MOT: ana mu\r\n%trn: where is it?"
```

### Lookarounds:

You can switch on [`PCRE`](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) by using `perl=T` and use lookarounds to achieve this.

```
gsub('[^\\pP]\\K(?=\\r\\n\\*)', '.', Data1, perl=T)
# [1] "%trn: dads sheep.\r\n*MOT: hunn.\r\n%trn: yes.\r\n*MOT: ana mu\r\n%trn: where is it?"
```

The **negated** [Unicode property `\pP`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) class matches any character except any kind of punctuation character.

Instead of using a capturing group, I used `\K` here. This escape sequence resets the starting point of the reported match. *Any previously matched characters are not included in the final matched sequence*. As well, I used a [Positive Lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds) to assert that a carriage return, newline sequence and a literal asterisk character follows.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it:

Capture group:
`gsub("([^[:punct:]])\\r\\n\\*", "\\1.\r\n*", Data1)`

Positive lookbehind (non-capturing group):
`gsub("(?<=[^[:punct:]])\\r\\n\\*", ".\r\n*", Data1, perl=T)`

**EDIT:** fixed the backslashes and removed the uncertainty about R support for these.

Comment: Nice to show several ways. Perhaps a third way with the `\K` feature (`Perl=T`). All backslashes must be escaped `\r` => `\\r`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: thank you for the help! I think the backslashes are correct now.

Comment: Thanks @CasimiretHippolyte & @BrianStephens! I used \r\n instead of \\r\\n and it runs like a dream.